# Generic python module

Tags: python, generics, python-module

I have a set of python modules that share most of the code with the unique difference of the class they are instantiating.

I thought I could implement a template and render the module with the class I want to instantiate every time, but I reckon this is not the best solution, so I would like to know if there is any way to have a kind of generic module to avoid replicate code.

An example of my situation.

Module A:

```
from table import BusinessRules
from best_practice import BP_BusinessRule
from query import new_query, _and, _or

def process_BR(conn, args):
    query = new_query('active', '=', 'true')
    table = BusinessRules(conn)
    res = table.get_records(query=query)
    for record in res['records']:
        bp = BP_BusinessRule(record)
        for check in args:
            fcheck = getattr(bp, check, None)
            if fcheck:
                fcheck()
```

Module B:

```
from table import ClientScript
from best_practice import BP_ClientScript
from query import new_query, _and, _or

def process_CS(conn, args):
    query = new_query('active', '=', 'true')
    table = ClientScript(conn)
    res = table.get_records(query=query)
    for record in res['records']:
        bp = BP_ClientScript(record)
        for check in args:
            fcheck = getattr(bp, check, None)
            if fcheck:
                fcheck()
```

I would like to have a module like this, and I don't know how to achieve this.

```
from table import <Generic>
from best_practice import BP_<Generic>
from query import new_query, _and, _or

def process(conn, args):
    query = new_query('active', '=', 'true')
    table = <Generic>(conn)
    res = table.get_records(query=query)
    for record in res['records']:
        bp = BP_<Generic>(record)
        for check in args:
            fcheck = getattr(bp, check, None)
            if fcheck:
                fcheck()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from query import new_query, _and, _or

def process(table_cls, bp_cls, conn, args):
    query = new_query('active', '=', 'true')
    table = table_cls(conn)
    res = table.get_records(query=query)
    for record in res['records']:
        bp = bp_cls(record)
        for check in args:
            fcheck = getattr(bp, check, None)
            if fcheck:
                fcheck()
```

And then you could either use

```
process(ClientScript, BP_ClientScript, conn, args)
```

to call the function, or use partial

```
import functools
process_CS = functools.partial(process, ClientScript, BP_ClientScript)
```

and then just `process_CS(conn, args)` the way you do it now.